Why Nodemailer in an Astro project is not sending mail in production?
I am using astro for a project and trying to use nodemailer for my contact form. This sends mails to my expected mail just fine. But not sending mail in production. This is deployed on netlify.
export const prerender = false;
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer";
import RawLayout from "../layouts/RawLayout.astro";

if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
    try {
        const data = await Astro.request.formData();
        const name = data.get("name");
        const email = data.get("email");
        const subject = data.get("subject");
        const message = data.get("message");

        const emailBody = `Full Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nSubject: ${subject}\n\nMessage:\n${message}`;
    
        const transporter = createTransport({
            service: "gmail",
            auth: {
                user: "****@gmail.com",
                pass: "****",
            }
        });
    
        async function main() {
            const info = await transporter.sendMail({
                from: "****@gmail.com", // sender address
                to: "****@gmail.com", // list of receivers
                subject: " New Response", // Subject line
                text: emailBody, // plain text body
            });
        }
        main().catch(console.error);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    }
}

this is my netlify log:

ERROR  Error: Connection timeout     at SMTPConnection._formatError
(/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:798:19)
at SMTPConnection._onError
(/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:20)
at Timeout.
(/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:237:22)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)     at
process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {   code:
'ETIMEDOUT',   command: 'CONN'

The local dev environment did not had any problems.

You're getting this error because the transport configuration variables are more than likely incorrect. I've had issues using service: "gmail" before, while following some guide about MongoDB, but the below configuration fixed the error for me (obviously not my own configuration but just stripped down to essentials):
const transporter = createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465, // port for SSL
  secure: true, // use TLS
  auth: {
    user: "****@gmail.com",
    pass: "****",
  },
});


Another thing to note is that you cannot use your personal password if you have 2FA enabled - you will have to generate an app password as detailed here
